# Como personalizo un navbar bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Buen día a todos espero puedan ayudarme.
Estoy utilizando la librería Bootstrap 5 para realizar un navbar.

Mi problema es el siguiente al visualizar mi pagina en dispositivos móviles mi navbar aparece estilo "hamburguesa" por así decirlo lo cual debe de ser así ya que eso dicta la documentación.

sim embargo me gustaría mostrar en dispositivos móviles el navbar de diferente forma en lugar de mostrar mi menú delegable me gustaría mostrar una pila de botones con las opciones.

espero puedan ayudarme de antemano gracias.

Comment: A qué te refieres con "pila de botones"? Puedes adjuntar una imagen de referencia.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder. me gustaría que en dispositivos móviles mi navbar si visualice como lo muestro en la primera imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo como esto ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown link
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```